# Configuring socket.io in firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, socket.io

I am currently working on a node.js-based socket.io service in my project.

The socket functionality which I am using is supported by the node server.

I have a doubt regarding the socket.io usage

Can I have the same functionality(above mentioned) working in the firebase realtime database?

Answer (score 1):

Socket.IO provides the following key features:

Real-time analytics - Push data to clients that gets represented as real-time counters, charts or logs.
Binary streaming - Starting in 1.0, it's possible to send any blob back and forth: image, audio, video.
Instant messaging and chat - Socket.IO's "Hello world" is a chat app in just a few lines of code.

Some of the features offered by Firebase are:

Add the Firebase library to your app and get access to a shared data structure. Any changes made to that data are automatically synchronized with the Firebase cloud and with other clients within milliseconds.
Firebase apps can be written entirely with client-side code, update in real-time out-of-the-box, interoperate well with existing services, scale automatically, and provide strong data security.
Data Accessibility- Data is stored as JSON in Firebase. Every piece of data has its own URL which can be used in Firebase's client libraries and as a REST endpoint. These URLs can also be entered into a browser to view the data and watch it update in real-time.